# Is double Q-learning redundant when using target networks?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Generally speaking, the purpose behind target networks is to reduce the impact of current changes on the model. i.e. if I performed action `a` and got some reward `r`, I want to reduce the impact of this specific tuple on the model.

When using double-q learning, I keep a different model for action choosing and reward estimation, also to make the model more robust.

But, and here is my question, generally speaking, both of those methods delays some samples to gain robustness, in slightly different scheme, and as I see it they are solving the same problem. So are they redundant?

Answer (score 2):

No, double Q-learning is not redundant, since that is not the main motivation for double Q-learning. The abstract of the paper says

> In particular, we first show that the recent DQN algorithm, which
>   combines Q-learning with a deep neural network, suffers from
>   substantial overestimations in some games in the Atari 2600 domain.

And then

> We propose a specific adaptation to the DQN algorithm and show that
>   the resulting algorithm not only reduces the observed overestimations,
>   as hypothesized, but that this also leads to much better performance
>   on several games.

So a side-effect of DDQN is to mitigate the "moving target" problem, which the target network also solves. However, that is not the main point. The main point is to reduce over-optimism